# An inequality about the sum of some unit fractions with a property

Tags: inequalities

**Question** : Is the following true for any $n,N\in\mathbb N$?

$$\sum_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_N=n,\  k_i\ge0\in\mathbb Z}\frac1{\prod_{j=1}^{N}\{(N-1)k_j+1\}}\le 1$$

**Motivation** : I've known the $N=3$ case :

$$\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3=n,\  k_i\ge0\in\mathbb Z}\frac1{(2k_1+1)(2k_2+1)(2k_3+1)}\le 1$$

I proved this inequality by estimating the left hand side with integral. After proving this, I reached the above expectation by using computer. The above expectation seems true, but I'm facing difficulty. I would like to know how to prove this (if it's true) and any relevant references.

**Remark** : This question has been [asked previously on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520220/sum-k-1k-2-cdotsk-n-n-k-i-ge0-in-mathbb-z-frac1-prod-j-1n-n-1k) without receiving any answers.

*Update* : I'm going to show the proof for $N=3$ case without using integral. This is because it seems that this idea can be generalized (though I'm facing difficulty).

For any non-negative integer $n$, 
$$\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3=n,\  k_i\ge0\in\mathbb Z}\frac1{(2k_1+1)(2k_2+1)(2k_3+1)}\le 1$$

**Proof** : Let $A_n$ be the left hand side, and suppose that $\sum$ represents $\sum_{k_1+k_2+k_3=n,k_i\ge 0\in\mathbb Z}$. Noting that $(2k_1+1)+(2k_2+1)+(2k_3+1)=2n+3$, we get
$$\begin{align}A_n & =\sum\frac{(2k_1+1)+(2k_2+1)+(2k_3+1)}{(2n+3)(2k_1+1)(2k_2+1)(2k_3+1)}\\
 & =\frac{1}{2n+3}\sum\left\{\frac{1}{(2k_1+1)(2k_2+1)}+\frac{1}{(2k_2+1)(2k_3+1)}+\frac{1}{(2k_3+1)(2k_1+1)}\right\}\\
 & =\frac{3}{2n+3}\sum\frac{1}{(2k_1+1)(2k_2+1)}\\
 & =\frac{3}{2n+3}\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k_1+k_2=j,k_i\ge 0\in\mathbb Z}\frac{1}{(2k_1+1)(2k_2+1)}\\
 & \le \frac{3}{2n+3}\left(1+\frac 23 n\right)=1\end{align}$$
Here, I used
$$B_0=1, B_j\le \frac 23\ (j=1,2,\cdots,n)$$
where
$$B_j=\sum_{k_1+k_2=j,k_i\ge 0\in\mathbb Z}\frac{1}{(2k_1+1)(2k_2+1)}.$$

Comment: Dear @mathlove: Could you please try to add a top level tag to this question? Thank you.

Comment: @RicardoAndrade: Well, I know neither what the top level tag is nor how to add it.

Comment: The top level tags are tags like 'nt.number-theory' and 'at.algebraic-topology' which start with a two letter code. They roughly follow their arxiv counterparts. These tags can be added like any other tag, such as the tag 'inequalities' already present in this question. You only have to edit the question and add another tag. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Ricardo Andrade : Yes, your explanation is perfect, but the problem is that I have no idea. I would like you or any person to add suitable tag(s). Could you please explain why adding a top level tag is needed?

Comment: It is recommended to always use top level tags whenever possible. Most importantly, top level tags (and a few others like 'linear-algebra') provide the highest level subject classification at mathoverflow. Also, they are more stable than most other tags, and their meaning also tends to be better established. Ideally, in the long term, this would help in archiving and finding mathoverflow questions.

Comment: Sometimes, it can be hard to find an appropriate high level tag for a question. For example, I am not sure what the appropriate top level tag is for the present question, if there is any. Perhaps 'ca.analysis-and-odes' or 'nt.number-theory'? That is actually why I asked you to add a top level tag instead of doing it myself. In any case, even if it is not always possible, I think it would help greatly if you could try to provide a top level tag (or a close enough "big" tag, like 'linear-algebra') to your future questions.

Comment: @Ricardo, I thought of those same two tags, but I'm not sure either one is appropriate. I have also tried, without any success, to find a full listing of two-letter-code tags in use here.

Comment: Dear @Gerry Myerson: I absolutely agree that this question is hard to tag. Regarding the list of top level tags, I believe they are the same as the arXiv math tags. Further, it could be argued that most tags on the first page of the tag list are big enough to function essentially like a top level tag.

Comment: @Ricardo, yes, but it would be nice (in my opinion) if there were a list of arXiv tags readily available on this website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting an answer just to inform that the question has received an answer by Ivan Loh on MSE.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520220/sum-k-1k-2-cdotsk-n-n-k-i-ge0-in-mathbb-z-frac1-prod-j-1n-n-1k

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I want to use displays.  What you are asking is whether the coefficients of the taylor expansion of
$$\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(N-1)k+1} \right)^N$$
are all at most 1. Unfortunately the summation is a hypergeometric function that doesn't have a general simplification.  You can easily prove the conjecture for small $n$ and all $N$, or for small $N$ and all $n$ by expanding it.  In general you might be able to bound it with a contour integral or something like that.  I believe it is true.

Comment: Actually, after this is said, you should have extremely strong willpower to suppress the natural desire to recall that the function with all coefficients $1$ is $\frac 1{1-z}$ and to raise both sides to the power $\frac 1N$, i.e., to try to check if the coefficients of $(1-z)^{-1/N}$ are at least $\frac 1{(N-1)k+1}$. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment rather than an answer, since I only have plausible strategies to suggest. But I'm new here and don't have enough reputation to leave comments.

**Plausible Strategy #1:** As Brendan says, your sums are coefficients in the Taylor expansion of $$S_N(x) = \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(N-1)k+1} \right)^N.$$ I computed some expansions of these series and it looks like, perhaps, the coefficient of $x^n$ ($n\ge 2$) increases monotonically w.r.t. $N$. You could try to prove this and also prove that the limit of each coefficient as $N\to\infty$ is 1. I think I can show that $S_N(x)$ approaches $\dfrac 1{1-x}$ pointwise for $x\in (-1,1)$, which, though not sufficient for what you want to do, is at least encouraging.

**Plausible Strategy #2:** If we group like terms in your unit fraction sum, we can express it as a sum indexed over partitions of $n$. I'm too lazy to type the general formula but here it is for $n=3$, which ought to be suggestive enough:
$$\left(\frac{N(N-1)(N-2)}{3!}\cdot\frac 1{N^3}\right) + \left(\frac{N(N-1)}{1!1!}\cdot\frac 1{(2N-1)\cdot N}\right) + \left(\frac{N}{1!}\cdot\frac 1{3N-2}\right)$$
Here the terms correspond to $\pi=(1,1,1),(2,1),(3)$ respectively. The coefficients are just garden-variety multinomial coefficients. Now if we consider the terms corresponding to partitions with $r\ge 3$ parts, their numerators are $< (N-1)^r$ and their denominators are $> k(N-1)^r$, where $k$ is the leading coefficient. So, all of these terms undershoot their limits as $N\to\infty$.

When $n$ is large, almost all partitions of $n$ have 3 or more parts, so (a) your conjecture seems likely to be true and (b) you may be able to prove it by bounding a relatively small and simple subset of the terms.